# intersection multiplicity and partial derivatives of algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

this will probably be an easy-to-answer and a not-well-posed question, since I'm a total beginner in the field, but here goes:

Let $V(F)$ and $V(G)$ be two projective curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ ($F,G\in\mathbb{F}[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ homogenous polynomials) and $P\in V(F)\cap V(G)$ a point. Let $\mu_P(F,G)$ denote the intersection number (multiplicity), i.e. the number, defined in [Fultons book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) on p. 36, section 3.3 and also chapter 5. **Is there any relationship between $\mu_P(F,G)$ and the possible equality of partial derivatives** 
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}\!\!\!(P)\overset{?}{=}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_i}\!\!\!(P),\;\ldots,\;\frac{\partial^k F}{\partial x_i^k}\!\!\!(P)\overset{?}{=}\frac{\partial^k G}{\partial x_i^k}\!\!\!(P)\;?$$
**Do the equalities hold for $k=\mu_P(F,G)$?** If not, what is the correspondence? I assume degrees of $F$ and $G$ must be involved?

Thank you.

P.S. Some references from (preferably recent) books are highly desirable.